# FileStream with querystring in filename?

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I have a need to be able to open a file on disk but pass in parameters to that file via a querystring. It's a .SWF file, so I'm passing in the parameter necessary to get it to load correctly.

The code I'm using to do so is:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\file.swf?key=value", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

I'm getting an error opening the file: "Invalid characters in path" because of the "?" in the filename. Is there any way to load a file from disk into a FileStream object using a querystring in the filename?

Comment: I don't get it : a file is a file you're not executing anything when you get a file, you just get its content , so why would you send parameters ? what do you want to do ?

Comment: I have a variety of reasons for doing so, going into them all is a little outside the scope of the question. On a high level, the .SWF I'm loading (file.swf in my example) is a shell. The parameter I'm sending will actually be "Filename=realSwfFile.swf" which is the .SWF it loads with the correct content. I'm loading this into a Flash object that deals with these types of things and it uses a FileStream as it's base when loading a Flash file. It's a proof of concept for my boss.

Comment: querystring is a http/web concept... when you're requesting ie http://www.some.thing/file.swf?key=value, the qs is not passed to the file itself but the flash runtime running inside your browser can ask what qs was used to request the file. I don't know what runtime you're loading the file into, but it must have some kind of method to set the qs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem by putting my two SWF files on a web server and using the following code. Not exactly production ready code, but it illustrates the concept.

```
private static FileStream GetFileStream()
{
    string url = @"http://www.someurl.com/shell.swf?Filename=actualfile.swf";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    byte[] result = null;
    int byteCount = Convert.ToInt32(response.ContentLength);
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        result = reader.ReadBytes(byteCount);

    return new FileStream(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't do what you're trying to do. When you load a file from disk the querystring does not exist as a concept. It will only return the bytes contained in the SWF file.

The querystring matters at the execution level.